# How do I replace sequences of TRUE values with values indicating where they begin and end?

Tags: r

This seems like it should be a straightforward application of `which`, but I can't figure it out.  I have a matrix indicating whether a person was present or absent in a given survey wave.  I would like to convert it to a list of vectors, one list element per row of the matrix, indicating the ranges of time that a person is present.  Here's a working example of what I'm trying to do:

```
in.wave <- structure(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE), .Dim = c(108L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("wave5", 
"wave6", "wave7", "wave8")))

head(in.wave)
#      wave5 wave6 wave7 wave8
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [6,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

# Current approach is pure brute force:
possibilities <- expand.grid(list(c(T, F), c(T, F), c(T, F), c(T, F)))
output <- list(
  c(5.0, 8.0),
  c(5.4, 8.0),
  c(5.0, 5.4, 6.4, 8.0),
  c(6.4, 8.0),
  c(5.0, 6.4, 7.4, 8.0),
  c(5.4, 6.4, 7.4, 8.0),
  c(5.0, 5.4, 7.4, 8.0),
  c(7.4, 8.0),
  c(5.0, 7.4),
  c(5.4, 7.4),
  c(5.0, 5.4, 6.4, 7.4),
  c(6.4, 7.4),
  c(5.0, 6.4),
  c(5.4, 6.4),
  c(5.0, 5.4),
  c(0)
)

desired <- apply(in.wave, 1, function(trial) {
  output[[which(apply(possibilities, 1, function(x) all(trial == x)))]]
})

head(desired)
# [[1]]
# [1] 5.0 6.4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 5.0 7.4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 5 8
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 5 8
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 5 8
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 5 8
```

As the sample code shows, I'm currently doing this by brute force -- I'm enumerating all 2 ^ 4 possibilities, writing down what the output should be, and then looking up the correct output for each row of `in.wave`.  Since I'll be expanding this to 8 columns, I would rather not write out all 2 ^ 8 possibilities.

The desired output is a list of vectors of even length, where each pair of elements indicates when someone enters and leaves the survey.  So, for example, if you have a person who appears in all the waves, the desired output would be the vector `c(5.0, 8.0)`, and if you have a person who is absent in wave 7, then the desired output would be `c(5.0, 6.4, 7.4, 8.0)`.

If people couldn't be missing in a wave in the middle, you might use something like `range` with `which` to get the values where they were present.  But having multiple spells is throwing me off.  Any ideas how to solve this concisely?

Comment: My first efforts would start with results of  `apply(in.wave, 1,rle)` and that the numbering would start with the first TRUE.

Comment: @42 Thanks!  That was a good suggestion -- I posted an answer that makes use of it.

Answer (score 1):

Following [42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/42)'s suggestion, I put together a function that makes use of `rle`.  This seems to give the right answer, but hopefully someone else on here will have a more elegant solution.

```
makeJoinLeaveVector <- function(x) {
  # Recodes a logical vector into a set of paired values indicating when people
  # enter or leave a population
  #
  # Args:
  #   x: a logical vector
  #
  # Returns:
  #   A vector of length(rle(x)$values) * 2 with paired values indicating 0.6
  #   before each first value of TRUE in a set of them, and .4 after each last
  #   value of TRUE in a set of them.
  stopifnot(is.logical(x))

  # Get the run length encoding
  x.rle <- rle(x)

  # Now save a vector for each of the TRUE values
  is.true <- which(x.rle$values)

  out <- c(is.true, is.true + x.rle$lengths[is.true]) - 0.6
  names(out) <- NULL

  # Recode first and last possible values
  out <- ifelse(out == 0.4, 1.0, out)
  out <- ifelse(out == 4.4, 4.0, out)

  return(sort(out) + 4)
}

desired <- apply(in.wave, 1, makeJoinLeaveVector)

head(desired)
# [[1]]
# [1] 5.0 6.4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 5.0 7.4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 5 8
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 5 8
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 5 8
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 5 8
```

Comment: Seems sufficiently compact to be called "elegant" , although I thought you would also need to use `append` in order to drop in endpoints for combinations like TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't more elegant, but I thought I'd add it now I've written it.
The end bits of the code could probably be written much more cleanly.

The approach is to calculate `in.wave[, 2:4] - in.wave[, 1:3]` which gives a -1 when someone exits the survey and a 1 when someone enters the survey.

```
times <- c(5, 5.4, 6.4, 7.4, 8)

# exiting gives a -1
#   entering gives a 1
#   No change gives a 0
transitions <-  in.wave[, 2:4] - in.wave[, 1:3]

# Find the entrance and exit points of the survey
exits <- apply(transitions, 1, function(x) times[which(x == -1) + 1])
entrances <- apply(transitions, 1, function(x) times[which(x == 1) + 1])


# Combine entrances and exits
desired <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(in.wave)), function(x) sort(c(entrances[[x]], exits[[x]])))

# If no entrances, subject must have been in study from the beginning
desired <- 
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(in.wave)), function(x) if(length(entrances[[x]]) == 0){
                                               c(times[1], desired[[x]])
                                             } else {
                                               desired[[x]]
                                             })
# If no exits, subject must have remained in study until the end.
desired <- 
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(in.wave)), function(x) if(length(exits[[x]]) == 0){
                                               c(desired[[x]], times[5])
                                             } else {
                                               desired[[x]]
                                             })
```